# Making private repo inside an organization available to only some members

Tags: github, access-rights, github-organizations, private-repository

I am a part of a GitHub organization. I created a private repository inside this organization. Now, I see that all members of the organization get read access to it by default; however, I only want to collaborate with a few of them and do not want others to have any access to the content of this repository at this point in time. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Probably not, and you could install [git](https://git-scm.com/) on your own server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible.

#### WIth teams

First, the base permission of an org must be set to `No permission`. Then you need to make a team with the people you want to have `read` access or higher. Then you need to add the team and give them the access level you want them to have on the `Collaborators and teams` page in the settings for the repository.

#### Without teams

First, the base permission of an org must be set to `No permission`. Then go to the `Collaborators and teams` page in the settings. Then add the users you want to have access to the repository and give them the access level you want them to have.

Comment: This does not serve the purpose. If my base permission is set to `read`, then even after creating a team and assigning access level `triage` or higher does not affect the visibility of the repository to the members that are not part of the team. They can still see the repository content.

The solution I found that works for me is to ask the owner to change the base permission to `none`, and then I can individually add the collaborators to my repo and give them the desired level of access. This completely hides the repo from the members I do not add as collaborators.

Comment: @bumble this works if the repository is public or privet

Comment: I didn't understand. So you mean setting base permissions to `none` and adding members to the repo individually works well or the one you described in your answer?

Comment: @bumble I'm sorry I miss read your question. I thought you said you want everybody to have `read` access but only some `write` access. I have edited my answer